# Custom tool shortcut visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, customtool

Is there a way to create a shortcut for a custom tool in visual studio? At the moment I have to navigate to the tool in the solution, right click and run custom tool. It would be nice if I could either bind a shortcut key or run the tool from the toolbar. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

- Go to `Tools` -> `External tools`
- Configure your tool
- Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`
- In *Show commands containing* type: *Tools.ExternalCommand*
- Choose the command you want and set a shortcut for it.

In the `External tools`, the gotcha is that the number of the external tool is the position in the list.

Comment: I tried this but it will only run .exe files, I should have explained that mine is just a .tt template. I did discover the "Transform All T4 Templates" command but I only want to do them one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, right now I can't help you further: T4 Templates are in my "Things to learn" stack.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`..

Look for command `Project.RunCustomTool` or the command you actually want.

Comment: Ah that's good. The thing is with this method I still have to navigate to my custom tool in the solution first, is there a way I can quickly access it in the toolbar like a shortcut or to bind the shortcut key without having the tool selected first?