# How can navigate a callstack from a log in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, callstack

If I have a log file (from a crash reporter), how can I make it so I can easily navigate the callstack in Visual Studio? It's just a list of files with line numbers:

```
c:\agent\build\source\game\game_sdl.cpp:1485 in StepFrame
c:\agent\build\source\game\game_sdl.cpp:1942 in game_sdl_main
c:\agent\build\source\sdl2\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c:82 in main_getcmdline
c:\agent\build\source\sdl2\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c:98 in main
...\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288 in __scrt_common_main_seh
```

I don't have a crash dump.

*See also [How can navigate a callstack from a log in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146439/how-can-navigate-a-callstack-from-a-log-in-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a vscode solution.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's Output window has a secret ability to jump to files. We can leverage this by creating an External Tool.

### Clipboard Dumper External Tool

Add an External Tool to dump the log contents to the Output window and if it's in the correct format, Visual Studio will jump to file and line when you double click on the entries.

The callstack output must be absolute file paths and a line number:

```
absolute/file/path.cpp:3434
```

Tools > External Tools... > Add

Configure it like so:

- Title: `Dump Clipboard`
- Command: `Powershell.exe`
- Arguments: `-command Get-Clipboard`
- Use Output window: `true`

[image: External Tools window showing the tool configuration.]

Then copy your callstack to the clipboard and run the tool to dump the text to the Output window.

You can even [bind it to a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930468/custom-tool-shortcut-visual-studio).

### Resolving Paths

If your callstack lines use paths different from your local paths (like `c:/agent/build/project` instead of `c:/code/project`), then create those folders and link the project folder to your actual project:

```
mkdir c:\agent\build\
mklink /d c:\agent\build\project c:\code\project
```

(You may need to [run `mklink` in an Administrator cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/a/968225/11808).)

### My paths are in the wrong format

If Visual Studio doesn't like your paths, then you'll have to write a program that grabs the clipboard, reformats it, and prints it.

For example, to be able to handle the callstacks from the [Call Stack window's "Copy With Source Paths" option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72322716/79125) you could use powershell to strip the leading "at" with the Arguments: `-command (Get-Clipboard).Replace('at ', '')`