# How can navigate a callstack from a log in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, callstack

If I have a log file (from a crash reporter), how can I make it so I can easily navigate the callstack in Visual Studio Code? It's just a list of files with line numbers:

```
c:\agent\build\source\game\game_sdl.cpp:1485 in StepFrame
c:\agent\build\source\game\game_sdl.cpp:1942 in game_sdl_main
c:\agent\build\source\sdl2\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c:82 in main_getcmdline
c:\agent\build\source\sdl2\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c:98 in main
...\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288 in __scrt_common_main_seh
```

I don't have a crash dump.

I have an [answer for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77146432/79125), but I'd like a solution for people on my team who use vscode. The extensions and options are completely different between VS and vscode, so I need a different solution. (There's no External Tools menu in vscode.)

Comment: @Vaishali Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code aren't the same thing.

Comment: with the extension (I wrote) [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) you can define rules to match and create ctrl+click links

Comment: @starball: If I have a file `output.log` that contains the contents of my question, and I open it in vscode (File > Open File...), then I can't Ctrl-click or right click on the file paths to jump to them. Would you expect that to work?

Comment: ah never mind. I didn't read the question carefully and thought this was something you were looking at in the integrated terminal. Yeah this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @starball: Your comment helped push me toward an answer: a task to dump the clipboard into the terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, you can setup commands as **[Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode)**.

Open your workspace tasks (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> Open Workspace Tasks). Inside the `"tasks": []` list, add this task:

```json
            {
                "label": "Dump Clipboard",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "Powershell.exe",
                "detail": "Send clipboard to Terminal -- make callstacks ctrl-clickable.",
                "args": [
                    "Get-Clipboard"
                ],
                "problemMatcher": []
            },
```

Now you can copy the part of the log containing the list of files and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> Run Task <kbd>Enter</kbd> Dump Clipboard <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the task. It will dump whatever was on your clipboard into the Terminal window. Jump to files (and lines) in the Terminal Window with **Ctrl-click**.